# Reading from a bound pipe using Proc::Async

Tags: asynchronous, process, pipe, stdout, raku

[`Proc::Async`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Proc::Async) is one of the classes that Perl 6 uses for interacting asynchronously with the system. The documentation specifies this way [to bind to the output of an external program](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Proc::Async#method_bind-stdout):

```
my $p = Proc::Async.new("ls", :out);
my $h = "ls.out".IO.open(:w);
$p.bind-stdout($h);
await $p.start;

say "Done";
```

(Some modifications added, like awaiting for the promise). However, I don't know how to print the output of this `$p`. Adding a `tap` yields this error:

```
Cannot both bind stdout to a handle and also get the stdout Supply
```

in block  at bind-stdout.p6 line 8

There are [`print` and write methods](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Proc::Async#method_write) in the documentation, but I don't know how to `read` from it other than reading the file. Any idea?

Comment: @HåkonHægland right. Clarified in the post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure you can do that (the error is very explicit). As a workaround you could get a regular tap and print to stdout and a file in the same block:

```
my $p = Proc::Async.new("ls", :out);
my $h = "ls.out".IO.open(:w);
$p.stdout.tap(-> $str { print $str; $h.print($str) });
await $p.start;

say "Done";
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct. You either bind the handle or read from it by getting the `Supply`. We only get to bind one thing to the target process standard handles, thus the exception here is just reflecting a lower-level restriction that Perl 6 can't really do much about.